# Docker Best Approach for JAVA Web application (Linux , Oracle DB,Application Server)?

Tags: docker

I am a newbie to docker , I need your help about the best approach to dockerize a Java Web Application that is deployed in one of the following application  servers (jboss , websphere , weblogic) and uses oracle database and communicate with C binaries that are host in a linux system.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check out dockerhub? There's tons of Java docker files to look at: e.g. Java JBOSS: https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=java+jboss&starCount=0 - this would be a good place to start.

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. You are just asking for "help" for which there isn't really any clear answer.